# Using NetDispatcherFaultException in OnDeserializing event

Tags: wcf, serialization

I have converted my asmx web service to a wcf service. I have some datatmembers in my datacontract which are to be marked as IsRequired. Now, if the client does not provide me with the required element value, the wcf service throws a System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispacherFaultException. But I want to throw a custom error message to the user. i have the

```
[OnDeserializing]
void OnDeserializing(StreamingContext context) {}
```

method written in my DataContract class. Is it possible to capture the NetDispacherFaultException in this function?